# Counting occurrence a record based on consecutive days

Tags: mysql

I have a query to display record of stationary issued according to date.

```
SELECT date,stationary_id FROM stationary_issued
```

How do i check if a stationary was issued in consecutive days.I have tried group by and sum row.

Current table

```
date       stationary_id
2019-04-01 2
2019-04-01 3
2019-04-01 4
2019-04-01 5
2019-04-02 3
2019-04-02 2
2019-04-03 3
```

Expected

```
stationary_id consecutive_occurrence
3             3
2             2
```

I have tried grouping date and stationary while counting stationary_id but the result is not correct

Comment: I see only 2 occurence of `stationary_id 3` current table data. Also `MySQL <> SQL Server`

Comment: @Arulkumar fixed. Any solutions??

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? For later versions of MySQL there exist window functions that simplify these type of queries

Comment: Also, you should either create a db<>fiddle (https://www.db-fiddle.com/) or similar, or post `CREATE TABLE`and `INSERT` statements. It's not particularly tempting to start solving an issue if one have to start by manually creating tables and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd argue your results are actually...

```
stationary_id consecutive_occurrence
3             2
2             1
```

You have 3 days present. Only two of those days are consecutive (04/02 and 04/03), meaning there was a day preceding them.

I'm making a few assumptions...

- Each record in the table is an occurrence; stationary was delivered that day
- A record is marked as a consecutive delivery, if (and only if) there was a delivery the prior day.
- Since we don't have data for 03/31, we can't say whether deliveries on 04/01 were consecutive.

Generating sample data matching your post...

```
create table #thinger ([date] date, stationary_id tinyint);
go
insert into #thinger ([date], stationary_id) values ('2019-04-01', 2);
insert into #thinger ([date], stationary_id) values ('2019-04-01', 3);
insert into #thinger ([date], stationary_id) values ('2019-04-01', 4);
insert into #thinger ([date], stationary_id) values ('2019-04-01', 5);
insert into #thinger ([date], stationary_id) values ('2019-04-02', 3);
insert into #thinger ([date], stationary_id) values ('2019-04-02', 2);
insert into #thinger ([date], stationary_id) values ('2019-04-03', 3);
go
```

Here is a quick and dirty query to retrieve the summation you asked for...

```
;WITH consecutive_stationary_orders AS (
    SELECT cday.[stationary_id]
         , (
            select 1 
              from #thinger pday
             where pday.[date] = DATEADD(day, -1, cday.[date]) 
               AND pday.stationary_id = cday.stationary_id
           ) AS was_consecutive
      from #thinger cday
)
SELECT [stationary_id], SUM(was_consecutive)
  FROM consecutive_stationary_orders
 GROUP BY [stationary_id]
HAVING SUM(was_consecutive) IS NOT NULL;
```

Forgive me. I used SQL/T-SQL syntax as I don't have a MySQL instance at this very second to use. But, this should give you an idea of what I'm doing.

First result set returns a list of dates, stationary issued (by ID), and whether that day's delivery was consecutive. The second query (wrapper) aggregates the first query. Whatever RDBMS you use, that's the approach I'd take.

Comment: will i die if i try to implement this in lumen? ;)

Comment: Life is full of risks :-) Na, stuff the statement in a string via a heredoc then pass the statement to your `app('db')->select($query);` method.

Answer (score 0):

> consecutive days

```
SELECT t1.stationary_id, MAX(DATEDIFF(t2.date, t1.date))
FROM stationary_issued t1
INNER JOIN stationary_issued t2 ON t1.stationary_id = t2.stationary_id
                               AND t1.date < t2.date
INNER JOIN stationary_issued t3 ON t1.stationary_id = t3.stationary_id
                               AND t1.date <= t3.date
                               AND t3.date <= t2.date
GROUP BY t1.stationary_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t3.stationary_id) = 1 + MAX(DATEDIFF(t2.date, t1.date))
```

PS. Not tested - no fiddle.